# Speed up InMemoryFileIndex for Spark SQL job with large number of input files

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an apache spark sql job (using Datasets), coded in Java, that get's it's input from between 70,000 to 150,000 files.

It appears to take anywhere from 45 minutes to 1.5 hours to build the InMemoryFileIndex.

There are no logs, very low network usage, and almost no CPU usage during this time.

Here's a sample of what I see in the std output:

```
24698 [main] INFO org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler  - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@32ec9c90{/static/sql,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
25467 [main] INFO org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.StateStoreCoordinatorRef  - Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
2922000 [main] INFO org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex  - Listing leaf files and directories in parallel under: <a LOT of file url's...>
2922435 [main] INFO org.apache.spark.SparkContext  - Starting job: textFile at SomeClass.java:103
```

In this case, there was 45 minutes of essentially nothing happening (as far as I could tell).

I load the files using:

```
sparkSession.read().textFile(pathsArray)
```

Can someone explain what is going on in InMemoryFileIndex, and how can I make this step faster?

Comment: Figured it out, I was passing too many files to sparkSession.read().textFile(70,000 paths...).  Spark apparently check's every path passed in for children, in case it's a folder, or glob pattern.  This was taking a very long time.

Comment: SimpleSam5 Can you elaborate more how did you find out Spark checks every path? Thank you!

Comment: I believe I found the code where it globs each path individually in sequence.   There may be way to parallelize this, but I found the best solution was to send it as few paths as possible, using complicated glob expressions where possible.  For example, I ended up using one path, full of "{foo,bar,foobar,barfoo}" expressions.

Answer (score 10):

The InMemoryFileIndex is responsible for partition discovery (and consequently partition pruning), it is doing file listing and it may run a parallel job which can take some time if you have a lot of files, since it has to index each file. When doing this, Spark collects some basic information about the files (their size for instance) to compute some basic statistics that are than used during query planning. If you want to avoid this each time you read the data in, you can save the data as a datasource table (it is supported from Spark 2.1) using the metastore and the saveAsTable() command and this partition discovery will be performed only once and the information will be kept in the metastore. Then you can read the data using the metastore

```
sparkSession.read.table(table_name)
```

and it should be fast since this partition discovery phase will be skipped. I recommend to see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwQel6JHMpA) Spark Summit talk in which this problem is discussed.