# Spark reading Partitioned avro significantly slower than pointing to exact location

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, avro, azure-databricks

I am trying to read partitioned Avro data which is partitioned based on Year, Month and Day and that seems to be significantly slower than pointing it directly to the path.
In the Physical plan I can see that the partition filters are getting passed on, so it is not scanning the entire set of directories but still it is significantly slower.

E.g. reading  the partitioned data like this

```
profitLossPath="abfss://raw@"+datalakename+".dfs.core.windows.net/datawarehouse/CommercialDM.ProfitLoss/"
 
profitLoss = spark.read.\
    format("com.databricks.spark.avro").\
    option("header", "false").\
    option("inferSchema", "false").load(profitLossPath)
 
profitLoss.createOrReplaceTempView("ProfitLosstt")

df=sqlContext.sql("SELECT * \
                             FROM ProfitLosstt \
                             where Year= " + year + " and Month=" + month_nz + " and Day=" + date_nz )
```

Takes around 3 mins

whereas this where I point to the exact location using a string builder, gets done in 2 secs

```
profitLossPath="abfss://raw@"+datalakename+".dfs.core.windows.net/datawarehouse/CommercialDM.ProfitLoss/Year=" +year +"/Month=" + month_nz + "/Day=" + date_nz
 
profitLoss = spark.read.\
    format("com.databricks.spark.avro").\
    option("header", "false").\
    option("inferSchema", "false").load(profitLossPath)

 
profitLoss.createOrReplaceTempView("ProfitLosstt")

df=sqlContext.sql("SELECT * \
                             FROM ProfitLosstt "
                              )
                  
display(df)
```

Looking at the physical plan for the 1st one (slower) does show that the partition filter is passed on

What could explain the discovery phase taking this long?

Any questions and I can elaborate.

Comment: can you do `df.explain` on the first one & put output here? I suspect is that there is no predicates pushdown

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned, the partition filter is getting passed on: Here is the physical plan from Spark UI:== Physical Plan ==
PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(Year#448), isnotnull(Month#449), isnotnull(Day#450), (Year#448 = 2020), (Month#449 = 6..., PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<MK_DatesID_TradeDate:int,MK_UCRAccountsID_AccountID:int,MK_ProductCategoriesID_ProductCate...

Comment: The time is spent on coming up with a job. For a long time, it just says "running command" without any job. when the job does start, it finishes fast. So, somehow the execution plan creation takes a long time?

Comment: From the driver logs- I see it is taking a lot of time to build up the InMemoryFileIndex. Around 2.18 mins . Looking at this now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53111210/speed-up-inmemoryfileindex-for-spark-sql-job-with-large-number-of-input-files

Comment: yes, that's explains it - to push filters, it needs to know where they could be applied...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,the reason for the slowness was because of building of InMemoryFileIndex.

Though partitioning pruning takes place, Spark needs to know about the partition and file info and that's where it needs that step.
This S.O post elaborates it : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53111210/speed-up-inmemoryfileindex-for-spark-sql-job-with-large-number-of-input-files)

So, the idea was then to create an external table, so that this information is built, which I did using a script like this (I used an inline schema, you can use a schema file if you have one)

```
create external table ProfitLossAvro 


partitioned by (Year int, Month int, Day int)

ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'


Stored As 

 inputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'

 outputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'

Location 'abfss://raw@datalakename.dfs.core.windows.net/datawarehouse/CommercialDM.ProfitLoss/'

TBLPROPERTIES (
    'avro.schema.literal'='{
      "name": "Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro.Specifications.ProfitLoss",
      "type": "record",
      "fields": [{ "name":"MK_DatesID_TradeDate", "type":["int", "null"]},{ "name":"MK_UCRAccountsID_AccountID", "type":["int", "null"]},{ "name":"MK_ProductCategoriesID_ProductCategoryID", "type":["int", "null"]},{ "name":"CurrencyCode", "type":["string", "null"]},{ "name":"ProfitLoss", "type":["double", "null"]},{ "name":"MK_PnLAmountTypesID_PLBookingTypeID", "type":["int", "null"]}]
    }');
```

But if you then query this table, you will get 0 rows. This is because the existing partitions are not added automatically. So, you can do that using

```
msck repair table ProfitLossAvro
```

and everytime you add data to your datalake, you can do an add partition.
Something like this:-

```
ALTER TABLE ProfitLossAvro ADD PARTITION (Year=2020, Month=6, Day=26)
```

If you then query your data using a command like the below, it will work much faster

```
df=sqlContext.sql("select * \
               from ProfitLossAvro \
               where Year=" + year + " and Month=" + month_nz + " and Day=" + date_nz)

display(df)
```