# spark read parquet with partition filters vs complete path

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a partitioned parquet data in hdfs example:
hdfs://cluster/stage/data/datawarehouse/table=metrics_data/country=india/year=2020/month=06/day=30/hour=23/<part-files.parquet>

I would like to understand which is the best way to read the data:

**df = spark.read.parquet("hdfs://cluster/stage/data/datawarehouse/table=metrics_data/country=india/year=2020/month=06/day=30/").where(col('hour') == "23")**

OR

**df = spark.read.parquet("hdfs://cluster/stage/data/datawarehouse/table=metrics_data/country=india/year=2020/month=06/day=30/hour=23")**

I would like to understand more in terms of performance and other advantages if any.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty straight forward, the first thing we will do while reading a file is to filter down unnecessary column using `df = df.filter()` this will filter down the data even before reading into memory, advanced files format like parquet, ORC supports the concept predictive push-down more [here](http://bigdatums.net/2017/08/29/what-is-predicate-pushdown/) , this enables you to read data in way faster that loading the full data.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think i was not clear on my query. I understand that we applying filter conditions to partitioned parquet during the read step pushes the filter to source itself. I want to understand if giving the complete path is not good in performance compared to adding filter conditions. 
Because both the step is going to hit the same path ultimately

Answer (score 1):

If you have a big hierarchy of directories/files, direct reading of single directory could be faster compared to the filtering, as Spark will need to build an index to apply that filter.  See the [following question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62532991/spark-reading-partitioned-avro-significantly-slower-than-pointing-to-exact-locat#comment110658966_62532991).

Comment: Thanks Alex, This helps. And yes i will try to run a tiny check by validating both ways of reading in terms of performance.

Comment: What if I have a more complex query @alex-ott, like a time window (2020-10-25 to 2020-11-10) ?

Comment: then you need to issue several separate reads, and do union...

Comment: ok thank you, I understand that reading multiple partitions is then better that filtering on multiple criteria? In other words, filter with time window vs read a list of directories

Comment: yes, when you read per partition, Spark won't read data that not in the partition key.  If you use window function, then data need to be read, and then filtered

Answer (score 0):

Please read through [this ariticle](https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/partition-filters-pushed-filters/). You can take a look at the phyical plan of the query. If you find it is using **PartitionFilters**, that means those two ways you described are not much different.